# SCons: How to make a library pick up CPPPATH options

Tags: c++, linux, scons

I have boost installed under `/home/username/local/include`. I want to compile a library with this set under CPPPATH.

SConstruct:

```
env = Environment(CPPPATH = '/home/username/local/include')
env.Library('MyLib', 'library.cpp')
```

library.cpp:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp> // library.cpp:1:32: error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory

void foo() { }
```

However, when I run `scons`, it gives the error `error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory`.

Doing the same thing for a program works just fine.

SConstruct:

```
env = Environment(CPPPATH = '/home/username/local/include')
env.Program('program.cpp')
```

program.cpp:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp> // works

int main() { return 0; }
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT

Here is the output:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o library.o -c -I/home/m/local/include library.cpp
library.cpp:1:32: error: boost/shared_ptr.hpp: No such file or directory
scons: *** [library.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Comment: Hmm... ok can you try building with '-k': Right now it is bailing on the library, but there is no evidence in that output that the program behaves differently. With '-k' it will try to build all targets ignoring failures. Please post the updated output.

Comment: And you should also post the contents of 'ls /home/m/local/include'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error on my system. Everything you have there looks right to me.

I created a faked out boost include setup, and used a different filename so it wouldn't accidentally reach into my real boost includes in /usr. I'm using SCons 2.0.1.

```
$ find /home/acm/local/include -type f
/home/acm/local/include/boost/not_a_boost_header.hpp
```

library.cpp:

```
#include <boost/not_a_boost_header.hpp> 

void foo() { }
```

program.cpp:

```
#include <boost/not_a_boost_header.hpp> 

int main() { return 0; }
```

SConstruct:

```
env1 = Environment(CPPPATH = '/home/acm/local/include')
env1.Library('MyLib', 'library.cpp')

env2 = Environment(CPPPATH = '/home/acm/local/include')
env2.Program('program.cpp')
```

Build results:

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o library.o -c -I/home/acm/local/include library.cpp
ar rc libMyLib.a library.o
ranlib libMyLib.a
g++ -o program.o -c -I/home/acm/local/include program.cpp
g++ -o program program.o
scons: done building targets.
```

Can you post the complete SCons output?

Comment: I posted it above. I have scons v2.1.0.r5357 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: I tracked this down to a bad link in the include folder. scons is in good shape.